# N+1 relationship in POJO defination

Tags: java

I have question regarding 1+N relation ship. I have designed POJO as below which has Workplace and Employee relationship.

1+N --> One company many employees

```
public class WorkplaceDetail implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -6760386803958725272L;
private int code;
private String plant;
private String compRegNum;
private String numOfEmps;
private List <Employee> employee = new ArrayList<Employee>();
      private Address address;
}

public class Employee{

private String empName;
private int empNumber;
      private Address address;
}
```

public class Address {

```
private String primaryPhone;
private String secPhone;
private String mobileNum;
private String fax;
private String zip;
private String add1;
private String add2;
```

}
**Or**

N+1 relationship where Employees belong to one workplace.

```
public class WorkplaceDetail implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -6760386803958725272L;
private int code;
private String plant;
private String compRegNum;
private String numOfEmps;   
}

public class Employee{


private String empName;
private int empNumber;
    private WorkplaceDetail WorkplaceDetail;
}
```

Please let me know which one is correct approach.

Comment: it is a good practice to have references in both the Pojo i.e, you need to have a reference of Child in Parent and Parent in Child. Hence, the correct solution is to have WorkPlace Pojo from first approach and Employee Pojo in the second approach in the final impl.

Comment: Thanks. Then if i have one more bean Address.(This address can be Emloyee address or Company address. In tat can i think i shld make it as 1 to 1 relationship right. For example : Company: address and Employee: address

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for you. Note this is just a snippet, config related things you should handle.

```
public class Address {

private String primaryPhone;
private String secPhone;
private String mobileNum;
private String fax;
private String zip;
private String add1;
private String add2;
//As you said one to one relationship
private Employee employee;
private WorkplaceDetail workplaceDetail;
}

public class Employee{

private String empName;
private int empNumber;
private Address address;
private WorkplaceDetail workplaceDetail;
}

public class WorkplaceDetail implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -6760386803958725272L;
private int code;
private String plant;
private String compRegNum;
private String numOfEmps;
private List <Employee> employee = new ArrayList<Employee>();
private Address address;
}
```

Hope this helps you...!